# How to stop spring sleuth from adding data to MDC

Tags: logging, spring-cloud-sleuth, mdc

Currently needed data such as spanId and traceId already logs, but sleuth also ads a lot of useless data do the MDC and since I'am using MDC quite heavily I really don't need al this excess data to be in the logs,
is there a way to stop Sleuth from writing data to MDC?

Comment: The spanId and the traceId are in the logs because of the MDC. What do you mean by lot of useless data?

Comment: @JonatanIvanov I mean that it also logs duplicated trace and spend ids and some other fields that I rather not see in my logs